# Guardando diccionario en un objeto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código:

```
class UserData:
    def __init__(self, user_information):
        self.user_information = user_information


class UserDataLoader:

    def load_user_data(self):
      D = []

      with open("client_admin_users.csv", "r") as csv_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for l in reader:
            datos = UserData(l)
            D.append(datos)
        return D

user_data = UserDataLoader()
users = user_data.load_user_data()
```

Lo que busco es poder guardar cada linea de un CSV en un diccionario y a su vez poder acceder desde `users` al valor que desee obtener, por ejemplo:

```
for user in users:
    print(user['email'])
```

Lo que esta adentro de los corchetes equivale a una columna del CSV, el problema que estoy teniendo, es que no puedo de la forma mencionada, debo primero llamar a la variable y después ya puedo obtener los valores que busco:

```
for user in users:
    print(user.user_information['email'])
```

Me gustaría poder hacer lo que busco sin la necesidad de llamar a `user_information`, cualquier sugerencia se agradece.

Comment: ¿El CSV trae la lista de campos en la primera fila? ¿Algo asi como "nombre, edad, email"? Si no, que campos esperas leer?

Comment: correcto @CandidMoe , en la primera fila vienen los headers que es lo que mencionas, nombre, apellido, telefono, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leyendo desde un archivo CSV bien formado, como este:

```
nombre,email,direccion
juan perez,jperez@gmail.com,Las Cañas 124
rodrigo soto,rsoto@hotmail.com,Alameda 1023
```

obtenemos un diccionario por cada línea usando el módulo `csv`:

```
{'nombre': 'juan perez', 'email': 'jperez@gmail.com', 'direccion': 'Las Cañas 124'}
{'nombre': 'rodrigo soto', 'email': 'rsoto@hotmail.com', 'direccion': 'Alameda 1023'}
```

Usaremos ese diccionario para crear un objeto de la clase User:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, datos):
        self.datos = datos

    def __getitem__(self, llave):
        return self.datos[llave]

    def __setitem__(self, llave, valor):
        self.datos[llave] = valor
```

Esta clase sólo tiene una variable, `self.datos`, que contiene el diccionario completo.

Para poder recuperar los campos por la llave (nombre, email, direccion) usando la notación `usuario['nombre']` redefinimos el método mágico `__getitem__`, que recibe la llave y devuelve el valor correspondiente desde el diccionario.

También redefinimos el método mágico `__setitem__`, con lo cual podemos asignar valores a una llave.

Con esto, el código se resume en:

```
usuarios = []
with open("clientes.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for linea in reader:
        usuarios.append(User(linea))
```

**Comprobación**

Este código recorre los usuarios para asignarles un numero de identificación, que guardaremos bajo la llave `id`. Esta dato no viene en el CSV, pero lo podemos agregar sin problemas.

```
i=1
for user in usuarios:
    user['id'] = i
    print(f"{user['id']} {user['nombre']} {user['email']}")
    i += 1
```

produce:

```
1 juan perez jperez@gmail.com
2 rodrigo soto rsoto@hotmail.com
```

Comment: gracias @Candid Moe, justo lo que buscaba